# argparse - Different mandatory / available parameters per action

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm looking to create an argument parser with the following structure:

```
options [ 'backup', 'consistency_check', 'backup_and_consistency_check']

--database [ required ]
--action [ required choice from list options ]
  --where_to_backup_to [ only required if --action is 'backup' ]
  --what_file_to_consistency_check [ only required if --action is 'consistency_check']
--clean [ optional ]
  --force [ optional if --clean is also in arguments ]
```

How can I implement optional arguments using the ArgumentParser module, depending on the choice which was made as another command line argument.

I'm looking to make the ArgParse fail if for example the command line arguments are

```
--d database_name --a backup --what_file_to_consistency_check /var/tmp/file.bak
```

This is what I've gotten so far (I know it's very little but I don't want to go in the complete wrong direction with subparsers if I haven't gotten it right from the start)

```
actions = ['backup', 'consistency_check', 'backup_and_consistency_check']

def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Parser for Backup / Consistency Check')

    parser.add_argument('--database', '-d', dest='db', help='Database name', choices=get_active_database_list())

    parser.add_argument('--action', '-a', dest='action', help='Action option', choices=actions)
    # --where_to_backup_to [ only if action = backup ]
    # --what_file_to_consistency_check [ only if action = cc ]
    parser.add_argument('--clean', '-c', dest='clean', help='Clean')
    # --force [ only available if --clean is also in arguments ]

    return parser
```

Comment: Give each action its own subparser. BTW, conventionally, you'd make action a positional argument.

Comment: Can you provide an example? It doesnt even have to be actual code - just a description? Can I add a subparser to the specific argument rather than the whole parser?

Comment: Being conditional to actions is what subparsers are *for*, so the examples in the docs all apply.

Comment: Will take another look at the doc - tis mind boggling stuff!

Comment: I've tried to make the title more descriptive of the actual question -- "Python Argument Parsing" can mean any number of things, and part of the goal of a question title is to be descriptive enough that other folks with the same problem can actually identify whether a given question (hopefully with answers) really *is* addressing the same problem they have.

Comment: BTW, amending a question in a way that makes existing answers invalid is frowned on here (re: the `--clean` / `--force` thing). And frankly, the typical way to handle that situation might be to have something more like `--force-clean`, or just to check at runtime for an invalid combination and explicitly call `parser.error("--force is only valid with --clean")` or similar.

Comment: Does the `action` always requires some sort of file or directory name?  If so it could be a positional or an optional with a generic flag.

Comment: action requires a value from the list of options and then the sub-command requires a directory or a file (depending on the action type) yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subparsers seem too complex at the moment, I think you can still get a useful parser without them:

```
def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Parser for Backup / Consistency Check')

    parser.add_argument('--database', '-d', dest='db', help='Database name', choices=get_active_database_list())

    parser.add_argument('--action', '-a', help='Action option', choices=actions)
    parser.add_argument('target', help='target for backup or check')
    parser.add_argument('--clean', '-c', help='Clean') # default dest is 'clean'
    parser.add_argument('--force', help='force clean')
    return parser
```

If `database` is required, you might want to add a `required=True` parameter to it.  Or make it a positional.  Otherwise consider what you will do if the user does not supply it.  I.e. if `args.db is None`?  Is there a default database that you can use?

It looks like all the action choices require a file or dir argument - the target for backup or checking.  Does it matter whether the user calls it '--where_to_backup_to' or '--what_file_to_consistency_check'?  By using a positional here I'm requiring them to give some sort of name, but it's up to you to interpret it according to the 'action'.

It looks like `force` is just a stronger version of `clean`.  What do you think the user wants if they specify `--force` but not `--clean`?  Here I accept both and let your code choose which makes most sense.

My philosophy is that the primary goal of a parser is figuring out what the user wants.  Error checking is most useful when it prevents ambiguous input.  But it shouldn't be picky.  A simple parser design is usually better than an overly complex one.

Answer (score 1):

I think making action a positional parameter with dynamic option parser is a good option:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    action = sys.argv[1]

    parser = create_parser(action)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: argparse has built-in support for subcommands -- use it, and your `--help` covers all possibilities, vs trying to hack something similar yourself. Also, that way you can have options *before* your arguments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to avoid using unneccessary if conditions and pulling variables out of arguments etc since the options also include another similar functionality - I've updated the code with a new --clean option, which then also allows for an optional --force (to force clean) -- and yes, to build on what Charles has said, ArgParse is intelligent enough to do the magic, so I'd like to utilize it to its maximum potential :)

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way to do this would look more like the following:

```
def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Parser for Backup / Consistency Check')

    parser.add_argument('--database', '-d', dest='db', help='Database name', choices=get_active_database_list())
    parser.add_argument('--timeout', '-t', dest='timeout', help='Timeout limit (in minutes)')

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    parser_backup = subparsers.add_parser('backup', help='Run a backup')
    parser_backup.set_defaults(action='backup') # or even pass the backup function itself, vs a string
    parser_backup.add_argument('dest', help='Where to backup to') # where to backup to

    parser_check = subparsers.add_parser('consistency_check', help='Run a consistency check')
    parser_check.set_defaults(action='consistency_check')
    parser_check.add_argument('source', help='What file to check for consistency')

    return parser
```

...with usage as:

```
# here, action='backup' and dest='/path/to/dest'
yourtool -d db -t 15 backup /path/to/dest
```

...or...

```
# here, action='consistency_check' and source='/path/to/content/to/check'
yourtool -d db -t 15 consistency_check /path/to/content/to/check
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually clears a lot of things up. By adding a subparser, this is just like adding another argument except this argument has optional arguments too. I was getting confused thinking I would add a subparser and then add backup as an argument to the subparser.. but backup is the subparser!

Comment: If `add_subparsers(dest='action')` you don't need the `set_defaults` statements (unless you want to set a function value).